# Angular 2 - Bootstrap (Ng2-Bootstrap) typeahead implementation

Tags: angular, bootstrap-typeahead, angular-bootstrap, ng2-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement the [NG2-Bootstrap typeahead](http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/index-bs4.html) with no success.

This is my code:

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';
import {TYPEAHEAD_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-bootstrap';
@Component({
selector: "side-bar",
directives: [TYPEAHEAD_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES],
template: `
<div class="searchArea" [ngClass]="{searchAreaForceLargeWidth: forceShowSearch}">
   <form class="searchBlock" [ngClass]="{searchBlockForceShow: forceShowSearch}">
        <div class="form-group">
       <input [(ngModel)]="asyncSelected"
       [typeahead]="getAsyncData(getContext())"
       (typeaheadLoading)="changeTypeaheadLoading($event)"
       (typeaheadNoResults)="changeTypeaheadNoResults($event)"
       (typeaheadOnSelect)="typeaheadOnSelect($event)"
       [typeaheadOptionsLimit]="7"
       placeholder="Locations loaded with timeout"
       class="form-control">
        </div>
   </form>
</div>
`,
})
export class SideBarComponent {
forceShowSearch = false;
showCalendar = false;
dateFrom = "01/01/2023";
doSearch;

///////////
private selected: string = '';
private asyncSelected: string = '';
private typeaheadLoading: boolean = false;
private typeaheadNoResults: boolean = false;
private states: Array<string> = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado',
    'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa',
    'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
    'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico',
    'New York', 'North Dakota', 'North Carolina', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
    'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont', 'Virginia', 'Washington',
    'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];
private statesComplex: Array<any> = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Alabama' }, { id: 2, name: 'Alaska' }, { id: 3, name: 'Arizona' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Arkansas' }, { id: 5, name: 'California' },
    { id: 6, name: 'Colorado' }, { id: 7, name: 'Connecticut' },
    { id: 8, name: 'Delaware' }, { id: 9, name: 'Florida' },
    { id: 10, name: 'Georgia' }, { id: 11, name: 'Hawaii' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Idaho' }, { id: 13, name: 'Illinois' },
    { id: 14, name: 'Indiana' }, { id: 15, name: 'Iowa' },
    { id: 16, name: 'Kansas' }, { id: 17, name: 'Kentucky' },
    { id: 18, name: 'Louisiana' }, { id: 19, name: 'Maine' },
    { id: 21, name: 'Maryland' }, { id: 22, name: 'Massachusetts' },
    { id: 23, name: 'Michigan' }, { id: 24, name: 'Minnesota' },
    { id: 25, name: 'Mississippi' }, { id: 26, name: 'Missouri' },
    { id: 27, name: 'Montana' }, { id: 28, name: 'Nebraska' },
    { id: 29, name: 'Nevada' }, { id: 30, name: 'New Hampshire' },
    { id: 31, name: 'New Jersey' }, { id: 32, name: 'New Mexico' },
    { id: 33, name: 'New York' }, { id: 34, name: 'North Dakota' },
    { id: 35, name: 'North Carolina' }, { id: 36, name: 'Ohio' },
    { id: 37, name: 'Oklahoma' }, { id: 38, name: 'Oregon' },
    { id: 39, name: 'Pennsylvania' }, { id: 40, name: 'Rhode Island' },
    { id: 41, name: 'South Carolina' }, { id: 42, name: 'South Dakota' },
    { id: 43, name: 'Tennessee' }, { id: 44, name: 'Texas' },
    { id: 45, name: 'Utah' }, { id: 46, name: 'Vermont' },
    { id: 47, name: 'Virginia' }, { id: 48, name: 'Washington' },
    { id: 49, name: 'West Virginia' }, { id: 50, name: 'Wisconsin' },
    { id: 51, name: 'Wyoming' }];
private getContext() {
    return this;
}

private _cache: any;
private _prevContext: any;

private getAsyncData(context: any): Function {
    if (this._prevContext === context) {
        return this._cache;
    }

    this._prevContext = context;
    let f: Function = function(): Promise<string[]> {
        let p: Promise<string[]> = new Promise((resolve: Function) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                let query = new RegExp(context.asyncSelected, 'ig');
                return resolve(context.states.filter((state: any) => {
                    return query.test(state);
                }));
            }, 200);
        });
        return p;
    };
    this._cache = f;
    return this._cache;
}

private changeTypeaheadLoading(e: boolean) {
    this.typeaheadLoading = e;
}

private changeTypeaheadNoResults(e: boolean) {
    this.typeaheadNoResults = e;
}

private typeaheadOnSelect(e: any) {
    console.log(`Selected value: ${e.item}`);
}
//////////

constructor() {
    this.doSearch = function() {
        //this.forceShowSearch = false;
        console.log("Search");
    };
}
}
```

The code above is basically the same of the sample page of the ng2-bootstrap page.

I cannot see results. The page get stucked in "Loading" and throw this exception:

```
angular2-polyfills.js:1243 SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
Evaluating http://localhost:3000/ng2-bootstrap
Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js
at SystemJSLoader.__exec (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:1395:16)
at entry.execute (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3521:16)
at linkDynamicModule (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3126:32)
at link (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:2969:11)
at Object.execute (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:3301:13)
at doDynamicExecute (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:703:25)
at link (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:905:20)
at doLink (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:557:7)
at updateLinkSetOnLoad (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:605:18)
at http://localhost:3000/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js:417:11
```

And I was wondering : Is this everything ? Maybe I missed something ?

Answer (score 1):

I would revert all the changes you made, until you don't have any more errors. Including all the imports you made in order to add the directive. Then add this:

```
import {TypeaheadModule} from 'ng2-bootstrap';
```

to your `app.module.ts` and add it to your imports like so:

```
imports: [
    ...,
    TypeaheadModule.forRoot()
],
```

Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an entry in the map block of your SystemJS configuration:

```
<script>
  System.configure({
    map: {
      'ng2-bootstrap': 'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap'
    },
    packages: {
      (...)
    }
  });
  System.import(...);
</script>
```

Comment: You mean...the main.ts ??? this one ? 
    import {bootstrap} from "angular2/platform/browser";
    import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/router";
    import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";

    bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);

Comment: No it's something (`System.config({ ... });`) you should have in your HTML entry file...

Comment: Thanks ! The scenario is still the same, but maybe we advanced some step...probably there is more missing steps or I made some mistaken in something. By the way I can see the module being loaded by system.src.js

Comment: Great if you can see the module being loaded!